# Настройка ЧПУ Woocommerce. Что нужно прописать?

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

Что нужно прописать, чтобы получить url вида http://www.site.com/категория/подкатегория/название-товара.html? Но подкатегории у товара может и не быть...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Настройка постоянных ссылок в WooCommerce

1. Итак, для начала заходим в административную панель и переходим в `Настройки -> Постоянные ссылки`.
   [image: введите описание изображения здесь]
2. Выбираем пункт `«Произвольная база»` и записываем туда конструкцию такого вида `/shop/%product_cat%`
   [image: введите описание изображения здесь]
   После этого шага у вас уже будут отображаться нормальные ссылки, но это еще не все. Для окончательной настройки ЧПУ нужно установить плагин `Cyr-To-Lat`, который будет преобразовывать названия всех категорий и товаров с русских букв на латинские.
3. Для установки плагина переходим в `Плагины -> Добавить новый`.
   [image: введите описание изображения здесь]
4. В строку поиска вводим `Cyr-To-Lat` и нажимаем `Enter` для поиска.
   [image: введите описание изображения здесь]
5. Находим нужный нам плагин и нажимаем `Установить`.
   [image: введите описание изображения здесь]
   После установки плагина не забудьте его активировать.
   [image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Вот и все! Вы успешно настроили постоянные ссылки (ЧПУ) в вашем WordPress интернет-магазине на базе плагина Woocommerce.

**Источник:**
[Настройка ЧПУ в WooCommerce](http://wordpress-club.com/nastroyka-chpu-postoyannyih-ssyilok-v-woocommerce)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: что толку что я ввел такие настройки чпу в вукомерс. В ссылках присутсвует слово безрубрики ,на русском, и плагин транслитератор установлен.

Comment: Вы издеваетесь что ли? Вопрос был как сделать что бы ссылка при просмотре товара и категории в начале осталавась одинаковой. А вы какую-то ересь тут понаписали